# What are enumerated attributes in HTML?

Tags: html

Some HTML documentation I've read refers to 'enumerated attributes'. What are they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An enumerated attribute is an attribute that has a fixed set of possible values. For example the tag `ul` has the attribute `type` which could have the values: `disc`, `square` and `circle`.

Source: [enumerated attribute types](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_attribute_types_enumerated.cfm)

Comment: That means most of html attributes are enumerated?

Comment: Ahh like mysql enum data type. Now it makes sense.

Comment: What would be an example of a not enumerated attribute in HTML?

Comment: @ElizaK. data attributes, rows cols (any attribute that accepts custom values)